# Is there any difference in performance when using a small pipe diameter for a greens bubbler?

Tags: airflow, pipelines, pneumatic, water-pressure

So a greens bubbler is a setup that helps the farmer cleaning greens/ gets/ fruits by agitating the water.
Details here: https://blog.uvm.edu/cwcallah/2021/10/06/building-a-better-greens-bubbler/.
In those examples the pipe used is 2". Whitney following explanation:

> Technical info on selecting a blower: The most common 1 hp jacuzzi blowers can provide 110 CFM maximum flow (at zero pressure) and 75 inch water column (inch wc) static pressure head (at 0 CFM flow). Blowers operate somewhere in between these two extreme conditions, for example 60 CFM at 30 inch wc back pressure. The back pressure is the combination of the water level (in inches) plus the pressure loss due to friction from air flow in the piping between the blower and the air holes (at 60 CFM in 2” Sch 40 PVC, this loss is 1 inch wc per 10 feet of pipe length). So with 24” of water level in the tank a typical blower can easily be placed 60 feet away using 2” PVC to bring the air to the bubbler.

I would like to know what is real happening there and if it is possible to use small diameter pipe like 3/4" (20mm) .

Comment: If 60' corresponds to 2" PVC, then if you reduce the diameter, expect more losses- your power will be spent moving air through a skinnier pipe.  It will however move some air as long as it does not need to push more than 75 inches of water (~2.7 psi). How much air do you need per minute? Have you considered perhaps 8' of 3/4"?

Comment: Hi @Abel , In my case motor will be 3 feet away. I just want to understand if smaller pipe is ok. Air flow in my case is same with 110 CFM. So same setup with their example, just smaller pipe.

Comment: I believe it should be functional.  With 24" of water, depth like in their example, you still have 50" of water to spare in pressure before you hit no flow.  If you place your blower above the water level, water won't flow into it so you can avoid needing additional valves for safety... Your major loss would probably be in necking the 2" down to 3/4". You may just have to adjust how long you use the bubbler based on cfm you do actually get.

Comment: A 3/4 inch pipe has 1/7 the volume of a 2 inch pipe.

Comment: @TigerGuy what are you trying to say?

Comment: @AndyAndy my point is there is clearly a performance impact

Comment: At 200+ mph, you're going to turn your greens to gook.